# call function in views.py from jquery

Tags: python, jquery, django, django-templates, django-views

I have `def main(request)` in `views.py` Wanna to make endless scrolling.

How can i call this func from jquery in my template:

```
    <script>
$(window).scroll(function () {
      if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
        //call main
      }
    });
  </script>
```

Comment: You make an AJAX call, and as URL you can use `{% url ... %]`.

Answer (score 0):

In urls.py you have to add the url that you will be calling. It could be something like:

```
url(r'^call-main/$', views.call_main, name='call-main')
```

And then the ajax call from the function that you wrote:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "{% url 'call-main' %}",
    type: "POST",
    data: { csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}' },
    success: function () {
        // something here on success
    },
    error: function () {
       // something here on error
    }
});
```

Comment: already have defined 'main' in urls.py, or i have override it ?
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.main, name='main'),
]

Comment: If you have it already in urls.py than the url for your ajax call will be {% url 'main' %}

Comment: thanks, but have error (index):1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)

Comment: You need to pass csrf token in ajax. Try to add:  data: { csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'} after 'type' in ajax.

Comment: now - Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier  in success: function () .  :-)

Comment: thanks, i`ve checked it in alert('sucess'), works, but I expected that the function 'main' will be called every time and i'll have endless scrolling.  But i have just alert('sucess') 
Sorry, I'm only a couple of weeks in web development. I do not understand many things :-)

Answer (score 0):

Add your URL in urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [url(r'^sample/$', main, name='main_view')]
```

then use URL in the template

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#url

```
{% url main_view %}
```